# Web Browser control in windows forms not showing image

Tags: html, css, winforms

I am developing an application that registers a student and then prints out an identity card.

On my main form, I have an image Picture box control in which the user loads the image of the student.This image box stores the image in the hard drive through the following code:

```
string result;

        DialogResult res = ofdDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            result = ofdDialog1.FileName;
            pbImage.ImageLocation = result;
            pbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pbImage.Load();
            System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pbImage.Image, pbImage.Height, pbImage.Width);
            img.Save(Path.GetFullPath("Images/1.jpg"));
        }
```

To print the i-card, I am using an web browser control to first preview it to the user. I have an html code in which I want to show the details of the student with their pictures, and some logos. Everything else is working fine, but the student image is not getting displayed in the web browser control. I am using the following code:

```
contents = contents.Replace("[StudentImage]",Path.GetFullPath("Images/1.jpg"));
```

contents variable contains the HTML,

Following is the part of the html that should show the image of student:

```
<div style=""float:right; width:100px;height:95px;"">
<img src=""[StudentImage]"" style=""width:85px;height:85px;"" />
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong when all other images are showing perfectly with this approach except for this?

Comment: you have to bind the new content after replace the image path to the webBrowser document

Comment: @ahmed mandour can you please elaborate, i am new to this and i don't know how to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, instead of

```
img.Save(Path.GetFullPath("Images/1.jpg"));`
```

i used

```
img.Save(Path.GetFullPath("Images/1.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The image is now displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to submit your HTML content to the webbrowser

```
 private void DisplayHtml(string html)
 {
     webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
     if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
     {
        webBrowser1.Document.Write(string.Empty);
     }
      webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
  }
```

The use line

```
DisplayHtml(contents);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing.

Comment: check if the image path is correct after replacing it

Comment: debug your code and post the html value in the contents variable to check the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use an absolute path for the image. I'm not sure what the WebBrowser's "current directory" would be.